# PHP form validation for a shop not working

Tags: php, forms, validation

So I tried to make a PHP form for my online shop, where a customer can enter their name, adress, email..., but the validation doesn't seem to work properly. It always stays on the same page(instead of going to the insert.php file) as if the entered data was wrong, even if it isn't.

```
<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = $codeErr = $cityErr = $streetErr = $fakturaErr = "";
$name_ok = $email_ok = $code_ok = $city_ok = $street_ok = 0;
$name = $email = $code = $city = $street = $info = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Pole wymagane";
    } 
    else{
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Dozwolone tylko litery"; 
        }
        else{
            $name_ok=1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["code"])) {
        $codeErr = "Pole wymagane";
    } 
    else {
        $code = test_input($_POST["code"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]*$/",$code)) {
            $codeErr = "Niewłaściwy format kodu"; 
        }
        else{
            $code_ok=1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
        $cityErr = "Pole wymagane";
    } 
    else{
        $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
     // check if city only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
            $cityErr = "Dozwolone tylko litery"; 
        }
        else{
            $city_ok=1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["street"])) {
        $streetErr = "Pole wymagane";
    } 
    else {
        $street = test_input($_POST["street"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$street)) {
            $streetErr = "Dozwolone tylko litery"; 
        }
        else{
            $street_ok=1;
        }
    }



    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } 
    else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Niewłaściwy format adresu e-mail"; 
        }
        else{
            $email_ok=1;
        }
    }

    $action = ""; 
    if($name_ok==1 && $code_ok==1 && $city_ok==1 && $street_ok==1 && $email_ok==1) {
        $action = "insert.php";
    } 
    else {
        $action = "#";
    }

   /*if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
     $genderErr = "Gender is required";
   } else {
     $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
   }
  */
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>


<div class="all">
    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
        <font color="#A20B0B">*Pola wymagane</font><br><br>

        Imię i nazwisko: <input type="text" name="name">
        <span class="error"><font color="#A20B0B">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></font></span>
        <br><br>

        Kod pocztowy:
        <input type="text" name="code">
        <span class="error"><font color="#A20B0B">* <?php echo $codeErr;?></font></span>
        <br><br>

        Miasto:
        <input type="text" name="city">
        <span class="error"><font color="#A20B0B">* <?php echo $cityErr;?></font></span>
        <br><br>

        Ulica:
        <input type="text" name="street">
        <span class="error"><font color="#A20B0B">* <?php echo $streetErr;?></font></span>
        <br><br>

        E-mail:
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <span class="error"><font color="#A20B0B">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></font></span>
        <br><br>

        <label>Dodatkowe informacje: <textarea name="info" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        <br><br>

        Faktura:
        <input type="radio" name="faktura" value="tak">Tak
        <input type="radio" name="faktura" value="nie">Nie
        <span class="error"><font color="#A20B0B">* <?php echo $fakturaErr;?></font></span>
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="register" disabled> 
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the content of your Err variables as you have this problem?

Comment: What happens if you enter all things correctly 2 times in a row? Can you try that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You submit the input values, after you check whether the inputs are valid or not If no redirect to next index page.

As per your code $action will get empty value. Thats why Its not redirected

insert.php

```
    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Pole wymagane";
    } 
    else{
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Dozwolone tylko litery"; 
        }
        else{
            $name_ok=1;
        }
    }

    // Paste you other post values code here


    if($name_ok==1 && $code_ok==1 && $city_ok==1 && $street_ok==1 && $email_ok==1) {
       // Do INSERT
    } 
    else {
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
```

HTML

```
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

You validate all input and then show the HTML.

Alright so basically you have this:

`PHP Part with all validations on $_POST`

and beneath that the action

`<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">`

since PHP does it's thing when the page loads it sets the `$action` to `#` because it's the first page load and nothing has been entered. (all $_POST are empty)

Now when you enter everything correctly and hit submit it will send the user back to the same page because of `$action` being `#`. And now it will do this again:

`PHP Part with all validations on $_POST`

and the action:

`<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">`

However because you entered everything correctly the action is now `insert.php` instead of `#`.

Because the default action is now `insert.php` and PHP only does it's thing when the page loads. It will not check if the data is filled in another time. So basically if you now just hit `submit` again you will be send to `insert.php` even though all your inputs are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is here, you set the action after the submit.

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
```

At first loop $action is not recognized, so you don't have any action.